# Merge List of Strings via concatenation of elements in Java

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

I have a CSV file from which I read multiple columns (based on user input) as `List<String>` and want to produce a single `List<String>` such that each element of the new `List` is a concatenation of the corresponding elements in the individual `List`s separated by "_".

This would mean that the size of the resulting `List<String>` is the same as that of each individual `List`.

e.g.

**File**

> col1A, col2A, col3A
>
> col1B, col2B, col3B

**User input** (range: 1 to max number of columns in file)

> 2,3

**Output** : List with contents

> ["col2A_col3A", "col2B_col3B"]

Prefer a functional solution using Streams.

**An attempt at writing a one-liner:**

```
 Arrays.stream("2,3".split(",")
            .map(Integer::parseInt)
            .map(idx -> colProcessor.getColumn(idx)) // colProcessor.getColumn(idx) returns column with index 'idx' as List<String>
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This however, concatenates the 2 columns in to one `List` of size 2*`<size of each column>` which is not the desired goal.

Comment: Hello please read [mcve]. And provide the code that you have written so far and the issue you are facing.

Comment: You posted code requirements, but I don't see description of problem which is stopping you from writing your own code. Please [edit] your question and include your attempts/research.

Comment: Updated the question. Let me know if it makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why people insist on `Streams` and forcing them onto problems where they don't naturally fit.  I mean, you probably could do it with a `Stream`, but I'm pretty sure it will look very unpleasant.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a `reduce` which will take your `Stream<List<String>>` and turn it into a single `List<String>` with the concatenated results:

```
Arrays.stream("2,3".split(","))
      .map(Integer::parseInt)
      .map(idx -> colProcessor.getColumn(idx))
      .reduce(new ArrayList<>(), (a, b) -> IntStream.range(0, b.size()).mapToObj(i -> {
          if (a.size() != 0) {
              return a.get(i) + "__" + b.get(i);
          } else {
              return b.get(i);
          }
      }).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

In the reduce `a` starts out as an empty list (hence the size check so that `a.get` won't throw an `IndexOutOfBounds` exception on the first pass). On each pass you then take the accumulated results in `a` and append the values in `b`.  To do this we use `IntStream.range` which will give us a stream of indexes in the `b` array and inside that map we do concatenation.